# How to extract unique components from the list?

Tags: r, extract

I have a list with the following components;

```
list= c("a","b", "a,b", "a,b,c")
```

I need to extract the unique components ie to get

```
list 2= c("a", "b", "c")
```

I tried  strsplit function:

```
out <- strsplit(as.character(list),',')
```

but I am stuck at this step, cause i am not sure how to proceed further

Comment: `unique(unlist(strsplit(list, ",")))`

Comment: Oh.. so simple. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think you need just one more step `unique(unlist(out))`